# Using spark MS SQL connector PySpark causes NoSuchMethodError for BulkCopy

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-sql-server

I'm trying to use the [MS SQL connector for Spark](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector) to insert high volumes of data from pyspark.

After creating a session:

```py
        SparkSession.builder
            .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.2.0,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.1.2,com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.4.1.jre8,com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0')
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 6.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 233)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.writeToServer(com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ISQLServerBulkData)'
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark.BulkCopyUtils$.bulkWrite(BulkCopyUtils.scala:110)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark.BulkCopyUtils$.savePartition(BulkCopyUtils.scala:58)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark.SingleInstanceWriteStrategies$.$anonfun$write$2(BestEffortSingleInstanceStrategy.scala:43)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark.SingleInstanceWriteStrategies$.$anonfun$write$2$adapted(BestEffortSingleInstanceStrategy.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:1020)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted(RDD.scala:1020)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

When trying to write data like this:

```py
        try:
            (
                df.write.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark")
                    .mode("append")
                    .option("url", url)
                    .option("dbtable", table_name)
                    .option("user", username)
                    .option("password", password)
                    .option("schemaCheckEnabled", "false")
                    .save()
            )
        except ValueError as error:
            print("Connector write failed", error)
```

I tried different versions of spark and the sql connector but no luck so far.
I also tried using a jar for the `mssql-jdbc` dependency directly:

```py
SparkSession.builder
   .config('spark.jars', '/mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar')
   .config(...)
```

It still complains that it can't find the method, however if you inspect the JAR file, the method is defined in the source code.

Any tips on where to look are welcome!

Comment: I'm having same issue. Did you manage to get it up and running?

Comment: @marcin2x4 sadly not, if I do I will add the solution as an answer.

Comment: I got it up and running. Will post entire solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

We reproduced the same scenario in our environment and it's correctly working now.

> There is an issue in JDBC driver 8.2.2 you can use the older version for the library.

*Below is the code sample,*

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

Data got inserted into `table` from `pyspark`.

**Reference:** [NoSuchMethodError for BulkCopy](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector/issues/112).

Comment: Please see [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - images of text are unusable for many reasons.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't resolve anything. FYI, you are not using the MS SQL spark connector, you are using standard JDBC connector, if you want to change that, you have to change the format to "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark".

Answer (score 0):

Using `com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.4.1.jre8` is one thing but also you need proper version of MS' Spark SQL Connector, compatible with your Spark's version.

`com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12_3.0:1.0.0-alpha` and `com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.4.1.jre8` did not work for my case as I'm using AWS Glue 3.0 (which is Spark 3.1)

I had to switch to `com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0` as it's Spark 3.1 compatible.

```
def write_df_to_target(self, df, schema_table):
    spark = self.gc.spark_session
    spark.builder.config('spark.jars.packages', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.4.1.jre8,com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0').getOrCreate()
    credentials = self.get_credentials(self.replica_connection_name)
df.write \
    .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
    .option("url", credentials["url"] + ";databaseName=" + self.database_name) \
    .option("dbtable", schema_table) \
    .option("user", credentials["user"]) \
    .option("password", credentials["password"]) \
    .option("batchsize","100000") \
    .option("numPartitions","15") \
    .save()
```

Last thing. AWS Glue job must have `--user-jars-first: "true"` param.
This instruction indicates that provided jars are to be used in first order (aka - you override default ones).

Try to check if equivalent parameter is on your end.